# Правильно ли я делаю?

Tags: веб-программирование, perl

Всем привет!
Есть самописная гостевая книга на Perl.
IP и Words-фильтры. При совпадении в них, просто делаю так:

```
print "Location: /404.html\nContent-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Страницы 404.html на сервере не существует. В итоге получаем реальную 404-ю ошибку. Одно время спамеры/боты просто добивали, даже пришлось премодерацию включить. Ни капча, ничего ессно не помогало. А вот эта строчка, хотите верьте, хотите нет, помогла! Видимо у ботов проверка на 404 есть и если "пациент" отвечает подобной ошибкой, значит отваливаемся от него.
Ну а физических удаков-спамеров успокоила премодерация.
Конечно, в errorlog сервера ошибки пишутся, но от хостера пока замечаний небыло. Меня смущает только что я намеренно вызываю ошибку сервака. Не страшно? Там не мегабайты проходят, говорю - спамеры отвалились как по команде. Так, пара-тройка года за пол примерно.
Мне сайт достался в очень запущенном состоянии, гостевая там одной сплошной дырой была, и даже без регистрации - пиши кто хочешь сразу. Поэтому, видимо, попала во все мыслимые спам-базы. Вот, написал свою.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один лишний запрос сервер вряд ли испортит. Но если хочется сделать все совсем по науке, то можно явно возвратить 404 ошибку. То есть, распечатать где то такое

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Perl-test
Content-Length: 3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

404
```

здесь на самом деле много лишнего и много фейкового. Главное, что бы Content-Length соответствовал длине тела. Date и Server можно и не писать

Comment: Т.е. через http заголовок передать. Я понял, спасибо!

Comment: да, а  детали ответа всегда можно нагуглить.